# Reusable UICollectionViewCell not changing UIImageView property (showing duplicates)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with a reusable cell that contains a `UIImageView` but the collection view displays the same image in the image view for each cell item in the collection.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let path = indexPath.item
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "friendAvatar", for: indexPath) as! AvatarCollectionViewCell
    cell.avatarView.image = friends[path].userAvatar
    return cell

}


class AvatarCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    var avatarView = UIImageView()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        prepareForReuse()
        config()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func prepareForReuse() {

        avatarView.image = nil
        avatarView.removeFromSuperview()

    }


    func config() {

        avatarView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 64)
        avatarView.layer.cornerRadius = 64 / 4
        avatarView.clipsToBounds = true
        avatarView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        addSubview(avatarView)

    }


}
```

Comment: `let path = indexPath.row`

Comment: @Guardanis rows are for table views. He is using a collection view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are removing the image view from its superview in `prepareForReuse()` but you never add it back. `init()` will not be called when reusing a cell, and neither will `config()`. Unless you have a specific reason for it, you shouldn't need to remove the image view from its superview. Just setting its image to nil should be enough.

Also, set a breakpoint and verify that `friends[path].userAvatar` returns a valid path to an image.